# Can you be infected by two coronaviruses at once?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

E.g. could you be infected by COVID-19 as well as a different strand of coronaviruses (e.g. those that circulate in the population every flu season)?

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site — not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas. It is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, not medical or social aspects of biology. For one of these reasons I think  that your question on the coronavirus outbreak is off-topic here. Question of a medical nature might be on-topic at SE Medical Sciences. Otherwise you are advised to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: I honestly don't think this is a bad question... though I think you'll need to be a bit more detailed and probably have to do more research and [edit] to show exactly what research you've done and what is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes:

> Coinfections involving multiple HCoVs were also detected (Table 2).
>
> ...
>
> [image]

- [Human Coronaviruses HCoV-NL63 and HCoV-HKU1 in Hospitalized Children with Acute Respiratory Infections in Beijing, China](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3265292/), Advances in Virology (2011)